# Get customer "on-hold" order status total amount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

I'm trying to get the price of all products on hold (i.e user has placed order but haven't made a payment) by a user in woocommerce.

I have the following code which detects all products on-hold orders by a user

```
function get_user_on_hold_product_price() {

    global $product, $woocommerce;

    // GET USER
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // GET USER ON-HOLD ORDERS
    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type'   => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'wc-on-hold',
    ) );
```

I'm not sure what to do from here to get only the total price of all on-hold orders by the user.

Adding/hooking this function to a shortcode, like this;

```
add_shortcode('get_on-hold_price', 'get_user_on_hold_product_price')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the total amount of customer "on-hold" orders using a **[`WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)** for improved usability and compatibility:

```
add_shortcode('user_on_hold_total', 'get_user_orders_on_hold_total');
function get_user_orders_on_hold_total() {
    $total_amount = 0; // Initializing

    // Get current user
    if( $user = wp_get_current_user() ){

        // Get 'on-hold' customer ORDERS
        $on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'limit' => -1,
            'customer_id' => $user->ID,
            'status' => 'on-hold',
        ) );

        foreach( $on_hold_orders as $order) {
            $total_amount += $order->get_total();
        }
    }
    return $total_amount;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

To get a formatted total amount replace `return $total_amount;` by `return wc_price($total_amount);`

> **Shortcode usage: `[user_on_hold_total]`**

Related documentation: [Woocommerce `wc_get_orders()` and `WC_Order_Query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

Comment: Not sure why i'm getting `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WP_Post::get_total()` on line `$total_amount += $order->get_total();`

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy Sorry there was a missing `;` in my code.

Comment: i tried editing your code to add the semi-colon but stack requires me to edit 6 things. i have added the semi-colon but got that fatal error, that's why i added the comment, as i'm not sure what is happening or why i am getting the error

Comment: Okay... i got it to work... I added `$order = new WC_Order( $order->ID );` above the `$total_amount += $order->get_total();` and it works now

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy I have re updated my answer with a much better way, that is more secure and efficient… Try it.

Comment: The right way is to use it this way: `'status' => array('on-hold','pending')` and it works