# Woocommerce - how to display only on-hold orders using a shortcode

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode, orders, wordpress-shortcode, woocommerce-theming

By default Woocommerce orders table displays **all** available order **status** on the *My Account* page which is not sortable by customer, therefore I need to have a separate table for every unique order statue (example : 'on-hold' ) to display orders table based on only required statue.

I tried this code but it doesn't output the table:

```
/* Shortcode To Display Only On-hold Orders On A Custom Page */

add_shortcode('account_on_hold', 'get_customer_orders_on_hold');

function get_customer_orders_on_hold() {


  if( $user = wp_get_current_user() ){

    // Get 'on-hold' customer ORDERS
        $on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
            'limit' => -1,
            'customer_id' => $user->ID,
            'status' => array('on-hold'),
        ) );

    }
    return $on_hold_orders ;
}
```

Related Topic : [Get customer “on-hold” order status total amount in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54922294/4170774)

Your advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruvee's way is good to customize.
Alternatively, if you want output just the same as "my-account/orders", there is also the method to call the template.

```
add_shortcode('account_on_hold', 'get_customer_orders_on_hold');
function get_customer_orders_on_hold() {
    if( $user = wp_get_current_user() ){
        $customer_orders = wc_get_orders(
            array(
                'customer' => $user->ID,
                'limit' => -1,
                'page' => 1,
                'paginate' => true,
                'status' => array('on-hold'),
            )
        );
        ob_start();
        wc_get_template(
            'myaccount/orders.php',
            array(
                'current_page'    => 1,
                'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
                'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
            )
        );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

(Addition) The way to add custom menu on the myaccount.

```
// Add custom endpoint
add_action( 'init', function () {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'on-hold-orders', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
});

// Add custom menu
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', function ( $items ) {
    $new_items = array();
    foreach( $items as $key => $item ){// Loop menu items
        $new_items[$key] = $item;
        if( 'orders' == $key ) $new_items['on-hold-orders'] = __( 'On hold orders' ); 
    }
    return $new_items;
}, 20 );

// Output custom menu page template
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_on-hold-orders_endpoint', function( $current_page ) {
    $current_page = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page ); // With paginate
    $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( array(
        'customer' => get_current_user_id(),
        'page'     => $current_page,
        'paginate' => true,
        'status' => array('on-hold'),
    ));
    wc_get_template(
        'myaccount/orders.php',
        array(
            'current_page'    => absint( $current_page ),
            'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
            'has_orders'      => 0 < $customer_orders->total,
        )
    );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you! May I have my-account navigation menu beside this table?

Comment: Ok.  You don't need to use shortcode tag, if you just want to add extra menu on the Myaccount page. I revised the answer. Try it.

Comment: I forgot to say. You may be need to refresh Permalinks after insert functions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use woocommerce table template to generate the html table. You only need to put a conditional check before generating it.

> `woocommerce table template`
> +
> `if("On hold" == esc_html(wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status())))`

So you could set this up in multiple ways, for example it could be something like this:

```php
add_shortcode('account_on_hold', 'get_customer_orders_on_hold');

function get_customer_orders_on_hold()
{
  if ($user = wp_get_current_user()) {

  $on_hold_orders = wc_get_orders(array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'customer_id' => $user->ID,
    'status' => array('on-hold'),
  ));

  if ($on_hold_orders) :
?>
    <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <?php foreach (wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name) : ?>
            <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr($column_id); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html($column_name); ?></span></th>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach ($on_hold_orders as $order) {
          $order      = wc_get_order($order);
          $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
          if ("On hold" == esc_html(wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status()))) :
        ?>
            <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr($order->get_status()); ?> order">
              <?php foreach (wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name) : ?>
                <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr($column_id); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr($column_name); ?>">
                  <?php if (has_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id)) : ?>
                    <?php do_action('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order); ?>

                  <?php elseif ('order-number' === $column_id) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($order->get_view_order_url()); ?>">
                      <?php echo esc_html(_x('#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce') . $order->get_order_number()); ?>
                    </a>

                  <?php elseif ('order-date' === $column_id) : ?>
                    <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr($order->get_date_created()->date('c')); ?>"><?php echo esc_html(wc_format_datetime($order->get_date_created())); ?></time>

                  <?php elseif ('order-status' === $column_id) : ?>
                    <?php echo esc_html(wc_get_order_status_name($order->get_status())); ?>

                  <?php elseif ('order-total' === $column_id) : ?>
                    <?php
                    echo wp_kses_post(sprintf(_n('%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce'), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count));
                    ?>

                  <?php elseif ('order-actions' === $column_id) : ?>
                    <?php
                    $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions($order);

                    if (!empty($actions)) {
                      foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url($action['url']) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class($key) . '">' . esc_html($action['name']) . '</a>';
                      }
                    }
                    ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        <?php
          endif;
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  <?php endif; ?>

<?php }
}
```

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks but your suggested code does not work too! I get (Array) output instead of table columns content.

Comment: Well, i tested it on my default woocommerce lab, and works seamlessly fine. In order for you to be able to get it to work, i think we need to remove the return statement. I just updated my answer and removed `return $on_hold_orders;`

Comment: I think, solution offered by Mizuho Ogino is cleaner and more robust than my own solution.